# What textual evidence is there for the Orthodox Jewish Bible translation of John 8:25?

Tags: john, textual-criticism, translation-philosophy

John 8:25, Orthodox Jewish Bible (OJB)

> They were saying, therefore, to him, Who are you? Rebbe, Melech
> HaMoshiach said to them, Why should I even speak to you at all?

Compare this to (say) the Berean Study Bible translation of John 8:25

> “Who are You?” they asked. “Just what I have been telling you from the
> beginning,” Jesus replied.

These two versions are totally different - the OJB does not even have the reply of Jesus.  Does the OJB version have any justification? Does it use different source manuscripts?

Answer (score 2):

The translation of OBJ can be explained as follows:

> ```
>  8:25      ὅ τι {B}
> ```

> Since the older Greek manuscripts lack punctuation and are written without division between words, it is possible to interpret Τὴν ἀρχὴν … ὑμῖν in several ways:
> (1)      As a question, with ὅτι = why? (“Why do I speak to you at all?”).
> (2)      As an exclamation, with ὅ τι in the sense of the Hebrew ‮מָה‬ (“That I speak to you at all!”).
> (3)      As an affirmation, with ὅ τι and supplying ἐγώ εἰμι (“[I am] from the beginning what I am telling you” or “Primarily [I am] what I am telling you” or “[I am] what I have told you from the beginning”).

> Several Latin witnesses (and the Gothic), misunderstanding the Greek, translate Principium, qui et loquor vobis (“[I am] the Beginning, even I who speak to you”). The Ethiopic omits ὅτι (“[I am] the Beginning, and I told you so”). The Bodmer Papyrus II (66) reads, according to a marginal correction that may be by the original scribe, Εἶπεν αὐτοῖς ὁ Ἰησοῦς, Εἶπον ὑμῖν τὴν ἀρχὴν ὅ τι καὶ λαλῶ ὑμῖν (“Jesus said to them, I told you at the beginning what I am also telling you [now]”). --
> Metzger, B. M., United Bible Societies. (1994). A textual commentary on the Greek New Testament, second edition a companion volume to the United Bible Societies’ Greek New Testament (4th rev. ed.) (p. 191). London; New York: United Bible Societies.